# Replace sequence of integers in vector by single number

Tags: arrays, matlab

Let `A` be vector of integers in which I want to replace a sequence of numbers by a precise number.

**Example:**

```
A = [ 8 7 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ]
```

and I want to replace the sequence `1 2 3` by `9`.

The result would be:

```
B = [ 8 7 9 4 5 9 4 5 6 7 ]
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could be one approach with `strfind` and `bsxfun` -

```
pattern = [1 2 3];
replace_num = 9;

B = A
start_idx = strfind(A,pattern)            %// Starting indices of pattern 
B(start_idx) = replace_num  %// Replace starting indices with replacement
B(bsxfun(@plus,start_idx(:),1:numel(pattern)-1))=[]    %// Find all group
               %// indices of the pattern except the starting indices and
              %// then delete them
```

Comment: @user2129506 - Consider accepting one of the answers here if you no longer need help.  This tells the StackOverflow community that you are finished with this particular question and that other people can move on to answer other questions!

Answer (score 4):

You can abuse [**`strrep`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) for your array of integers:

```
%// given
A = [8 7 1 2 3 4 5 1 2 3 4 5 6 7]
seq = [1 2 3];
rep = 9;

%// substitution
B = strrep(A, seq, rep)
```

---

```
B =

     8     7     9     4     5     9     4     5     6     7
```

As in [Divakar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29394612/2605073) [**`strrep`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strrep.html) and [**`strfind`**](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) are actually supposed to be used for string manipulation, but they work like a charm also for numerical arrays. I suppose internally they work with the ASCII representation (or other encoding) anyway and just return the output values in the same class as the input values. For our advantage.