# How to find a particular array matching certain pattern in cell array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to know the index of row of cell consisting of particular array in particular column...

**Example:**

```
C{1,1} = [1 2 3];
C{1,2} = [4 5 6];
C{2,1} = [11 12 13];
C{2,2} = [14 15 16];
```

I want to get index as **1** when I search for `[1 2 3]` in column 1 (or) **2** when I search for [14 15 16] in column **2**. I tried using

```
index = find([C{:,1}] == [1 2 3])
```

But didn't get. Please help

Comment: and what do you want, when you search for `[4 5 6]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`cellfun`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cellfun.html) in combination with [**`strfind`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) and [**`isempty`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isempty.html) or [**`isequal`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isequal.html) directly.

```
pattern = [1 2 3];

out = cellfun(@(x) ~isempty(strfind(x,pattern)),C)
%// or as suggested by Luis Mendo
out = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,pattern),C)

ind = find(out)
```

if the order within the arrays does not matter, also the following using 
 [**`ismember`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) and [**`all`**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/all.html) is possible:

```
out = cellfun(@(x) all(ismember(x,pattern)),C)
```

---

```
out =
     1     0
     0     0

ind =
     1
```

---

Do all the arrays have the same length `n`? Then you could use a more vectorized approach with an optional if-condition to see if your result is valid. It may is not necessary, depending how sure you are about your pattern input.

```
n = 3;
pos = strfind([C{:}],pattern)
ind = [];
if mod(pos,n) == 1, ind = (pos - 1)/n + 1, end
```

---

Both variants give you the **linear index**, means for `pattern = [14 15 16];` it would return **4**. To get the **row indices** you need an additional step:

```
[~,row_ind] = ind2sub(size(C),ind)
```

Comment: But the`ismember` approach would also "find" `[3 2 1]` for example. Perhaps use `out = cellfun(@(x) isequal(x,pattern), C)`

Comment: @Luis Mendo, I haven't thought about that! thanks! one could use `strfind` as well like in my second approach.

Comment: @thewaywewalk I hadn't seen that other approach. Nice use of `strfind`. It's not well known (or documented?) that this function also works for numbers

Comment: @LuisMendo I haven't seen it documented, but it gets used a couple of times [**recently**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29393911/2605073).

Comment: @thewaywewalk Yes, I've used it myself in the past, and it's really handy

Answer (score 0):

Another approach Using [`pdist2`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/pdist2.html?refresh=true) instead of `ismember` and `all` from the other answer

```
pattern = [1 2 3];
out = cellfun(@(x) pdist2(x,pattern)==0,C);
ind = find(out)
```

Gives the same result as [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588425/2111163).